# Why is scipy.interpolate.bisplrep returning nan values?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate 3-d data. The data I have is: https://jumpshare.com/s/Xeezpl0LpdcqtiQayoa5

But the issue I am having is that `interpolate.bisplrep` returns nan (the 2nd index of the `tck` variable).
My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numpy.ma as ma
from scipy.interpolate import griddata,bisplrep,bisplev

vol = pd.read_csv('data1.csv',index_col='dte')


T=np.array(vol.index)
K=np.array(vol.columns)
valid_vol=ma.masked_invalid(vol).T

Ti=np.linspace(float(T.min()),float(T.max()),len(T))
Ki=np.linspace(float(K.min()),float(K.max()),len(K))

Ti,Ki = np.meshgrid(Ti,Ki)
T,K = np.meshgrid(T,K)

valid_Ti = Ti[~valid_vol.mask]
valid_Ki = Ki[~valid_vol.mask]
valid_vol = valid_vol[~valid_vol.mask]

iv_interpol=griddata((valid_Ti,valid_Ki), valid_vol, (Ti, Ki),method='linear')


tck = bisplrep(Ti, Ki, iv_interpol)

T_new, K_new = np.mgrid[Ti.min():T.max():80j, Ki.min():Ki.max():80j]

znew = bisplev(T_new[:,0], K_new[0,:], tck)
```

I am needing znew to be a function that I can plug in values znew(a,b) and then get an output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a data file that has missing data.  This missing data gets treated as NaN.  You are then attempting to take splines over data with NaN in it. (Try printing out `vol`).

Why does your file has missing data? Are you expecting those fields to be filled with some default field?

Comment: They’re supposed to be missing. I’m trying to interpolate those areas. I’m trying to eventually get a function where I can put a T and K as the params and get an output, i.e. vol(T,K)

Comment: Remove the NaNs when providing scipy with the data and then use scipy to interpolate those points.